# How does the pointer containing an address returned by address of operator assigned to a pointer variable?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-management

I understand the fact that we can't assign the address literal to a pointer variable directly, thus the address of operator(&) doesn't return an address of variable/operand as literal.

```
 int* ptr{ 0x7ffd78ad698c };  // Compiler error
```

Instead, it returns a pointer containing the address of the variable/operand, and then our pointer variable somehow manages to get only the address from the pointer containing an address returned by the address of operator(&).

How does the pointer variable only get address from the pointer containing an address returned by address of operator(&)? What is the lifetime/scope of the pointer returned by address of operator(&)? Is it get destroyed immediately after the pointer variable takes the address it contains?

Comment: Why don't you use `=` and a cast??

Comment: I am learning C++ and using uniform initialization. I didn't know about `cast`, but now I know. Thanks.

Comment: _"I am learning C++"_ Why did you use the [tag:c] tag here then?

Comment: I am sorry. My fault. It was recommended automatically and thought to add it to reach more people.

Comment: _"... and thought to add it to reach more people. "_ Never do that. The tags are meant to narrow the scope of the audience, not to unnecessarily broaden it. Answers for a c solution might be completely different and thus irrelevant.

Comment: Note: accessing the memory pointed at by `ptr`, `*ptr`, is very high risk because you cannot be certain that address contains a valid `int`. The compiler error is the compiler making sure that you really, *really* want to do this because outside of an embedded system this is almost always wrong

Comment: I want to nitpick one thing. You do not have an address literal in your example. That is an integer literal. The compiler complains because the types mimatch, and there is no implicit conversions between integers and pointers. The conversions must be explicit, via an appropriate cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confused about pointers.

First, the *only* reason you can't do

```
int* ptr{ 0x7ffd78ad698c }; // Compiler error
```

is because the compiler thinks it's silly and a mistake. If you add a cast, the compiler will absolutely let you do this.

```
int* ptr{ (int*)0x7ffd78ad698c }; // Compiles
```

(I'll also point out that most people would write this statement using `=`)

Second. Pointers don't have lifetimes. Well, `ptr` is a variable so it has a lifetime, but the address *stored in* `ptr` doesn't have a lifetime. The thing it points to is a variable which has a lifetime. But the address itself - the number `0x7ffd78ad698c` - does not have a lifetime. Your question: "What is the lifetime/scope of the pointer returned by `&`?" is like asking "What is the lifetime/scope of the number returned by `+`?"

Beware that when people say "pointer", sometimes they mean a pointer variable (which has a lifetime/scope because it's a variable), and sometimes they mean an address (which doesn't because it's not).

Comment: The general dichotomy is object vs. value.

Answer (score 1):

> address literal

There is no such thing as address literal in C++.

> ```
> 0x7ffd78ad698c
> ```

This is an integer literal.

> What is the lifetime/scope of the pointer returned by address of operator(&)?

Assuming it is applied to a pointer, the result is a prvalue.

An overloaded `operator&` results in whatever the overloading function returns. Overloading the unary `operator&` is very rare.